# How to implement captcha with in ASP.NET Core 5.0 app with IdentityServer?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, captcha

In an ASP.NET Core with Identity and IdentityServer4 - I need to add a safeguard for new users.

How do you implement a captcha/recaptcha?

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple code: https://github.com/Jarda29/GoogleReCaptcha.V3

1. Add the nuget (I actually used the source - its just one file really)
2. Scaffold `Register` from IdentityServer
3. Register your website with Recaptcha (you would need separate keys for prod and localhost)
4. Modify Register.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
                <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="captcha" id="captchaInput" value="" />
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=@Configuration["Recaptcha:siteKey"]"></script>
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('@Configuration["Recaptcha:siteKey"]', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
                $("#captchaInput").val(token);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

5. Modify Register.cshtml.cs

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!await _captchaValidator.IsCaptchaPassedAsync(captcha))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("captcha", "Captcha validation failed");
                }
                else
                {
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
```

6. Add to Startup.cs: `services.AddHttpClient<ICaptchaValidator, RecaptchaValidator>();`